# Does the orbital radius include the radius of the two objects?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

I am trying to find the force using $F=Gm_1m_2/r^2$ and the answers do not include the radius of the two objects just the "orbital radius." So does this mean the orbital radius includes the radius of the two objects?

Comment: the orbital radius is the radius between the two center of mass points. It  takes into account not only the radius but the density  and shape too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an object is spherically symmetric then (outside the object) its gravitational field is the same as a gravitational field of a point mass located at the centre of the object. This is known as the [Shell Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem) and dates back all the way to Isaac Newton.

In practice most large objects are approximately spherical, so we generally treat them as point masses, at least as a first approximation. So when you write:

$$ F = \frac{GMm}{r^2} $$

the $r$ is the distance between the point masses i.e. the distance between the centres of the objects. So we ignore the radii of the objects.

Even if the objects aren't spherical, as long as we are far away from them, i.e. a distance many times greater than the size of the object, we can still treat the object as a point mass and ignore its size and shape. However if we're up close, or if we want to be really precise, then we do have to take account of the size and shape of the gravitating objects. In that case the expression for the force becomes a great deal more complicated.

As an example of this, the gravitational interaction between the Earth and the Moon can be understood to pretty good accuracy by considering them both as point masses. However to get a really good description we have to take into account that the Earth is an oblate spheroid and not spherically symmetric. For example this causes the [precession of the equinoxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_precession).

Comment: Thanks, this question is about Jupiter and Metis, a moon of Jupiter. I think for this question we can assume  that they have uniform density. My question is whether or not orbital radius includes the radius of the two objects orbiting, or is it just the distance between the surface of the two orbiting objects.

Comment: @ajmlhkm: the orbital radius is the distance between the centre of Jupiter and the centre of Metis. That is we are treating both objects as point masses.